# Pdfcrop: Cannot call ghostscript `mgs' in Command Prompt

Tags: errors, windows, ghostscript, pdfcrop

On Windows 10, I am attempting to call `pdfcrop a.pdf` from the command prompt, but I get the following error:

```
!!! Error: Cannot call ghostscript `mgs.exe' (No such file or directory/The system cannot find the file specified)!
```

I have checked that `C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\` is in my `Path`, and that `mgs.exe` is in `C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\`.  I have attempted to run `pdfcrop a.pdf --gscmd=mgs.exe`, but I merely get

```
!!! Error: Cannot call ghostscript `mgs.exe' (No such file or directory/The system cannot find the file specified)!
```

Edit: Weirdly, executing `pdfcrop a.pdf` in the git shell works.  I now understand this problem even less.

Edit 2: The command `mgs` works in both the git shell and the command prompt.

Edit 3: `...>pdfcrop --debug` produces

```
...>pdfcrop --debug
* Perl executable: C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe
* Perl version: v5.24.2
* Perl product: ActivePerl, build 2403
* Pointer size: 8
* Pipe support: yes
* Fork support: no
* OS name: MSWin32
* Arch name: MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
* System: miktex
* Not found (mgs): mgs.exe
* Found (mgs): C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\mgs.exe
* Autodetected ghostscript command: mgs
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
Syntax:   pdfcrop [options] <input[.pdf]> [output file]
Function: Margins are calculated and removed for each page in the file.
Options:                                                       (defaults:)
--help              print usage
--version           print version number
--(no)verbose       verbose printing                         (true)
--(no)debug         debug informations                       (true)
--gscmd <name>      call of ghostscript                      (mgs)
--pdftex | --xetex | --luatex
                  use pdfTeX | use XeTeX | use LuaTeX      (pdftex)
--pdftexcmd <name>  call of pdfTeX                           (pdftex)
--xetexcmd <name>   call of XeTeX                            (xetex)
--luatexcmd <name>  call of LuaTeX                           (luatex)
--margins "<left> <top> <right> <bottom>"                    (0 0 0 0)
                  add extra margins, unit is bp. If only one number is
                  given, then it is used for all margins, in the case
                  of two numbers they are also used for right and bottom.
--(no)clip          clipping support, if margins are set     (false)
                  (not available for --xetex)
--(no)hires         using `%%HiResBoundingBox'               (false)
                  instead of `%%BoundingBox'
--(no)ini           use iniTeX variant of the TeX compiler   (false)
Expert options:
--restricted        turn on restricted mode                  (false)
--papersize <foo>   parameter for gs's -sPAPERSIZE=<foo>,
                  use only with older gs versions <7.32    ()
--resolution <xres>x<yres>                                   ()
--resolution <res>  pass argument to ghostscript's option -r
                  Example: --resolution 72
--bbox "<left> <bottom> <right> <top>"                       ()
                  override bounding box found by ghostscript
                  with origin at the lower left corner
--bbox-odd          Same as --bbox, but for odd pages only   ()
--bbox-even         Same as --bbox, but for even pages only  ()
--pdfversion <1.x> | auto | none
                  Set the PDF version to 1.x, 1 < x < 8.
                  If `auto' is given as value, then the
                  PDF version is taken from the header
                  of the input PDF file.
                  An empty value or `none' uses the
                  default of the TeX engine.               (auto)

Input file: If the name is `-', then the standard input is used and
the output file name must be explicitly given.
Examples:
pdfcrop --margins 10 input.pdf output.pdf
pdfcrop --margins '5 10 5 20' --clip input.pdf output.pdf
In case of errors:
Try option --verbose first to get more information.
In case of bugs:
Please, use option --debug for bug reports.
```

And `...>pdfcrop --debug a.pdf` produces

```
...>pdfcrop --debug a.pdf
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
* Restricted mode: disabled
* Option `pdfversion': auto
* Perl executable: C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe
* Perl version: v5.24.2
* Perl product: ActivePerl, build 2403
* Pointer size: 8
* Pipe support: yes
* Fork support: no
* OS name: MSWin32
* Arch name: MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
* System: miktex
* Not found (mgs): mgs.exe
* Found (mgs): C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\mgs.exe
* Autodetected ghostscript command: mgs
* Input file: a.pdf
* Output file: a-crop.pdf
* Margins: 0 0 0 0
* PDF header: %PDF-1.5
* Using PDF minor version: 5
* Running ghostscript for BoundingBox calculation ...
* Ghostscript call: mgs -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -c save pop -f a.pdf
* Cleanup
* Temporary files: tmp-pdfcrop-9720.tex
!!! Error: Cannot call ghostscript `mgs' (No such file or directory/The system cannot find the file specified)!
```

(Suggested by @Ulrike Fischer)

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: What happens if you add the miktex path at the begin of the path with `set %path%=C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64;%path`?

Comment: That's actually what I've currently got.

Comment: What is the output of `pdfcrop --debug`?

Comment: Placed in question.

Comment: Hm. You could try Heiko's script here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77741/pdfcrop-does-not-work. Perhaps it gives a clue what is not working. (The differences to my system are that I have an older perl, and miktex is not in C:\program files as I have a single user installation in a path without spaces.)

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer That was it!  I was missing `C:\Windows\System32` in my `Path`.  I don't know how I missed that question in my searches.  Thank you.  =)